# How to exclude cases from comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to exclude cases on a comprehension which return a None.
The following achieves it but results in calling the function twice!!!

```
>>> def func(x):
...     if x>10:
...         return None
...     else:
...         return x*2
...         
>>> result1=[func(x) for x in l if func(x) is not None]
>>> result1
[4, 8, 14, 6]
```

What would be the way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result1[:] = [x for x in map(func, l) if x is not None]
```

On Python 2.x use `itertools.imap`

**Note:** `filter(None, map(func, l))` would usually work but that would also remove `0` (since it is considered empty)

Comment: @IUnknown It returns an iterator instead of a list. Therfore it's more efficient for huge data sets, for small lists you won't see much of a difference

Comment: Just one more hitch - how do i call a map for a function which takes a couple of additional parameters - def func(x,multiplier).

Comment: @IUnknown You can either just change `map(func, l)` to `(func(x, multiplier) for x in l)` or use `from functools import partial` `map(partial(func, multiplier), l)`

Answer (score 2):

What about this code :

```
print([x*2 for x in l if x <= 10])
```

**Edit**

Generally it can take form of :

```
print([process(x) for x in l if is_valid(x)]
```

Comment: True  - but the function I have is much more complex and is not really dependent on the input solely.

Comment: In this case you can separate the functions. One will check if the element is valid for processing and the second one will process it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(x):
    if x>10:
        return None
    else:
        return x*2

lst = [2, 4, 12, 7, 30, 3]

# original
result0 = [func(x) for x in lst if func(x) is not None]

# map... on Python 2.x, use itertools.imap()
result1 = [x for x in map(func, lst) if x is not None]
assert result1 == result0

# generator expression
result2 = [x for x in (func(y) for y in lst) if x is not None]
assert result2 == result0

# rewrite function as a generator function
def func_gen(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        if x <= 10:
            yield x*2

# no need to filter; filtering happens in generator function
result3 = list(func_gen(lst))
assert result3 == result0


# build a filtering generator out of parts
def fn_x2(x):
    return x * 2

def filter_leq10(x):
    return x <= 10

def make_filtering_gen_func(fn, flt, name="anonymous"):
    def anonymous(iterable):
        for x in iterable:
            if flt(x):
                yield fn(x)
    anonymous.__name__ = name
    return anonymous

func_gen1 = make_filtering_gen_func(fn_x2, filter_leq10)
result4 = list(func_gen1(lst))
assert result4 == result0
```

Comments.

@jamylak already showed you how to solve it with `map()` or `itertools.imap()`.  But for some reason he/she showed rewriting an existing list using slicing.  I don't see any reason to do that, so I showed it with just binding to a variable name.

The more commonly recommended alternative to `map()` is a generator expression, so I showed how to use one inside a list comprehension.

But for cases like this, I usually prefer to rewrite the function as a generator that only yields the desired numbers.  You will be calling the function anyways, so instead of having it return a sentinel value for unwanted values, just have it yield only the wanted values.

And finally, the functional way to build the filtering generator out of parts!  You can pass in any function that takes one argument (and remember you can use `functools.partial()` to bind other arguments and get a function object that just takes one argument), plus pass in a filter function that selects values.  It builds a function object and returns it, which automatically handles the "boilerplate" for you of adding the `for` loop, an `if` test to filter, and then `yield` with the results.